# Overwrite customisations from another publisher

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We have found ourselves in a situation where solutions have been imported with a different publisher to normal. So now when we have done updates to any components that are also included in that solution in a solution with our own publisher the import fails.

Is there any way that we can get the newer customisations to go over the ones from the previous solution, preferably without removing the previous solution?

Thanks

Comment: Are these managed or unmanaged solutions?

Comment: They are all managed solutions

Comment: How critical is it to use the "normal publisher" instead of the "different publisher"? That would certainly be doable. Also, do you have SQL access if you need to 'hack' the database to make this work?

Comment: I guess it doesn't really matter which publisher we use, but it seems that they all need to be the same one in order for the solutions to import correctly. I do have SQL access